# How to get the img url from CKEditor 5 getData method?

Tags: ckeditor5

I use my own UploadAdapter to upload img in CKEditor 5.
The implementation method upload is below, just like the [the official guideline](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-UploadAdapter.html) description.

```
upload() {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.loader.file);
    data.append('token', this.token);
    data.append('key', guid() + '.jpg');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
            url: '{my server url}',
            method: 'post',
            data,
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            withCredentials: false
        }).then(res => {
            var resData = eval("("+res.data+")");
            resData.url = 'my own domain' + resData.url;
            resolve(resData);
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        });
    });
}
```

My server response is like: {uploaded: true
url: "***.jpg"}
And the code above work well.
The CKEditor can get the response.I can see the img in the editor:

[image: the success result]

But, view the img html code is not my expect, it's src attribute has the base64 otherwise my given url param:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4*********">
```

[image: the wrong img html tag]

And the editor's getData method can not get the img data:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
upload() {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', this.loader.file);
  data.append('token', this.token);
  data.append('key', guid() + '.jpg');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      url: '{my server url}',
      method: 'post',
      data,
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      withCredentials: false
    }).then(res => {
      var resData = res.data;
      resData.default = resData.url; <----------- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-UploadAdapter.html#function-upload
      resolve(resData);
    }).catch(error => {
        reject(error)
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks. I just use the ckeditor 4 old logic to return:  {uploaded: true url: "***.jpg"}.
As you say, the default field make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
CKEditor 5 with ckfinder plugin the upload image response should be as follows.

```
const response = {
          resourceType: "Files",
          currentFolder: {
            path: baseUrl,
            url: `${baseUrl}${url}`,
            acl: 255
          },
          fileName: name,
          url: `${baseUrl}${url}`,
          uploaded: 1
        }
```